# Click just one button through an overlaying div

Tags: css, html, styles, css-position

I have some normal content. Then i made another div that is going to be over everything, triggered with a button.

This div is with position absolute, background color: rgba, so it can be transparent.

When the div is displayed, the user shouldn't be able to click anything underneath it, ONLY one button (the one just mentioned).

I can't manage to achieve that, if I use pointer-events, it gives click access to everything under it.

I just want the button in the bottom div to be clickable when the div is on.

Thanks a lot.!

Comment: 'preventDefault();' is your friend, but this shouldn't be happening if your content is overlayed properly. Do you have an example we can look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want one button to be clickable with the overlay active, why not just make that button the only thing above the overlay?

You could then you jquery to modify the css of the given objects. If the overlay is active z-index the button to the top. If it is inactive, return the button to its normal state and hide the overlay. If you really want the button to look like it is under the overlay, you could even set a style to make it look faded (either via CSS opacity, or an alternative image)

http://jsfiddle.net/ckaufman/b6gza/

Comment: it has no z-index, just transparency.
'.yourDiv{
  position:absolute;
  top: 1px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
height: 200px;
background-color:rgba(255, 246, 142, 0.6);
border: solid;
border-radius: 10px;
border-color: brown;
display:none
}'

I think i can do that, repeat the button on the top div, and just set the same opacity to it :) thanks. The problem gonna be set it exactly above the other one. Or how can i take it to top?

Comment: on your overlay div it is already positioned: absolute so you can apply a z-index to it, let's say 100. Set your button position: relative and give it a z-index of say 150 to set it above the overlay.

Comment: the easiest form was to set z-index to the button, so it stays above even if the div comes, thanks =)

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked. Remember to mark this question as answered / closed unless there is anything else we can help you with

Comment: Yeah its working now, and i didnt gave opacity to it, its just like jumping when they display the (help) div with the z-index so they can re-click it to close it. looks great. thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 0):

first, why are you trying to overlay a "transparent div" over everything?

Secondly, you can solve your problem by checking every click event for the visibility of your transparent div.

```
function anyclick()
if(transparent div is visible)
   do nothing
else
   do something
```

well technically that will still make the buttons clickable although it won't fire any event.

Edit Edit: Are you z indexing your "transparent div" or not? that also might cause problem.

Comment: Its a help for the users, the div apears and has some tooltips that explain whats going on on the under content.

It has too many event clicks, now u mention zindex, i think i can set it to the button, so it comes up too. 
im not using zindex on my div.